# bs4: How to extract table "team-roster home" and "team-roster away"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the team lineup for the home and away teams from here: http://www.veikkausliiga.com/tilastot/2016/veikkausliiga/ottelut/498251/kokoonpanot/.

I have tried using tr and td tags, as well as with id and class tags. I cannot get any information from the table.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
    thePage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupData = BeautifulSoup(thePage, "html.parser")
    return soupData

def makeTableData(url):
    matchDataSaved= ""
    soup = make_soup(url)
    table = soup.find("table",{"class":"team-rosters home"})
    return table
```

I expected the table rows to show, but the code outputs None. How can I get the players lineup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're wanting the output. This does work as it returns the element taht has that table tag. You'd still need to go through it to get the tr and td tags.

The other option is since it does have the `<table>` tag, is just use Pandas and then manipulate the dataframes to extract what you want and in the format you want it. Probably not in the form I would like it, but gets you the data and you can work with it from there:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.veikkausliiga.com/tilastot/2016/veikkausliiga/ottelut/498251/kokoonpanot/'

tables = pd.read_html(url)
results = pd.DataFrame()

ix_list = [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
for ix in ix_list:
    results = results.append(tables[ix])

results = results.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
                          0       ...                       3
0             #21  T. Dähne       ...                     NaN
1           #15  V. Jalasto       ...               #3  Taiwo
2              #20  Vincent       ...                     NaN
3               #7  N. Alho       ...                     NaN
4             #25  D. Assis       ...                     NaN
5               #9  B. Span       ...         #11  J. Ibrahim
6  #4  P. Sparrdal Mantilla       ...         #7  T. Wirtanen
7            #1  W. Viitala       ...                     NaN

[8 rows x 4 columns]
```